# How to install ucp module in python? [dask]

Tags: python, protocols, dask, distributed-computing, ucx

I am trying to run on a dask cluster using the ucx protocol. I got to know from my admins that the protocol is installed as expected. I however receive the following error when I am trying to switch to the ucx protocol:

```
from ucp import get_config, get_ucx_version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ucp'
```

I have tried things like `pip install ucp`, `conda install ucp`, `conda install -c travis emi-ucp`, but now I should have some other or old `ucp` since I cannot import neither `get_config, get_ucx_version`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the most up-to-date information for [installing ucx](https://ucx-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#conda) recommends installing from the `rapidsai` conda channel, in case you haven't tried this already.